# Detect Memory Leaks in iOS Cordova 4.0 App

Tags: java, javascript, ios, cordova, memory-leaks

I have a iOS app based on Cordova/PhoneGap. When profiling my app with XCode Instruments I get the following output:

[image]

You can see that the memory consumption is always increasing.

**Is there a way to detect my JavaScript memory leaks in my Cordova App?**

Comment: Please provide more information. What are your suspicions? Are you using any Cordova plugins? Are you using a Javascript framework? Does your app create lots of DOM objects? Can your app also run in a desktop browser and can you see the memory leask there also?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use safari and attach the developer tools to your debugging device. Instruments is helpful for showing memory usage, but it can't see the code inside your cordova app.